# Sort icon change place after click on column

Tags: html, css

css is in index.html
When I click on column for sorting data, sort icon change her place.
The icon should stay at the same place.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwppgq-qfu2jh

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

edit your css styling like this (set `text-align: center` for centering the text horizontal, with a fixed `width` and `line-height` for "centering" vertical in your case):

```
th[sortable].desc:before, th[sortable].asc:before {
    content: 'a';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
```

notice that you have to adjust this styling, if you change the font-size (`line-height`) or you set a icon-font or whatever instead of a normal letter.